# Firebase Tools: How to avoid "out of memory" errors when setting database with a big JSON file? How to stream JSON via firebase-tools?

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-tools, jsonstream

We have a GitHub action that copies data from one Firebase project to another using `firebase-tools` (we are using the latest version, `9.11.0`) package:

```
firebase use fromProject && firebase database:get / -o export.json
firebase use toProject && firebase database:set -y / export.json
```

This has worked fine until our data has grown bigger and now we are getting the following error:

```
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

As a temporary fix, we’ve been able too apply node `--max-old-space-size` flag which simply increases memory available to node process:

```
node --max-old-space-size=4096 /home/runner/work/foo/foo/node_modules/firebase database:set -y / export.json
```

Considering our data will keep growing, we’d like to implement a proper fix, which in my understanding would be to set data by **streaming** the JSON. However, I’m not sure `firebase-tools` allow that. Searching through Github issues didn't yield anything useful.

Perhaps apart from streaming there is another useful approach in splitting a huge JSON file into chunks before setting them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have used the HTTP streaming with Firebase HTTP API in order to overcome the troubles of saving, modifying locally and uploading a HUGE (over 256mb) JSON file.

We built a function to HTTP pipe data stream from one project’s database to another:

```
async function copyFirebasePath(path, from, to) {
  // getAccessToken from https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/auth
  const fromAccessToken = await getAccessToken(from.key)
  const toAccessToken = await getAccessToken(to.key)

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let toRequest
    // create write request, but don’t start writing to it
    // we’ll pipe the read request as the data to write
    try {
      toRequest = https.request(
        `${to.databaseUrl}/${path}.json?print=silent`,
        {
          method: 'PUT',
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${toAccessToken}`
          }
        },
        (/* res */) => {
          resolve()
        }
      )
    } catch (writeError) {
      reject(writeError)
    }

    try {
      https
        .request(
          `${from.databaseUrl}/${path}.json`,
          {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${fromAccessToken}`
            }
          },
          res => {
            res.pipe(toRequest)
            res.on('end', () => {
              toRequest.end()
            })
          }
        )
        .end()
    } catch (readError) {
      reject(readError)
    }
  })
}
```

And we use it like this:

```
// get Object.keys from remote db
const shallowDB = await request({
  method: 'get',
  // note ?shallow=true here – prevents loading the whole db!
  url: `${from.databaseUrl}/.json?shallow=true`,
  options: {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${fromAccessToken}`
    }
  }
})
const dbKeys = Object.keys(shallowDB)
const keysToOmit = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']

try {
  await Promise.all(
    dbKeys
      .filter(dbKey => !keysToOmit.includes(dbKey))
      .map(key => copyFirebasePath(key, from, to))
  )
} catch (copyError) {
  console.log(copyError)
  throw new Error(copyError)
}
```